# Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not found asus TUF b550plus (intel AX200)

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, bluetooth

Many threads on this and I Have tried almost all of them and none of them work (this is super frustrating!)

Im using the ASUS TUF B550Plus wifi gaming motherboard, flashed to the latest BIOS. However, it keeps saying no bluetooth found in settings (see below)

[image]

I've tried alot of things from `sudo modprobe btusb` etc mentioned in the other threads but nothing works. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and kernel `5.11.0-37-generic`

Systemctl output

```
➜  ~ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-10-13 01:36:17 +08; 9min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 104679 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38354)
     Memory: 512.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─104679 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Oct 13 01:36:17 wboy systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Oct 13 01:36:17 wboy bluetoothd[104679]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Oct 13 01:36:17 wboy systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Oct 13 01:36:17 wboy bluetoothd[104679]: Starting SDP server
Oct 13 01:36:17 wboy bluetoothd[104679]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
```

Bluetoothctl output

```
➜  ~ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

lshw output

```
➜  ~ sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 44:af:28:34:ae:2c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode ip=192.168.1.93 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:34 memory:fc300000-fc303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 04
       serial: f0:2f:74:22:d9:e5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 ip=192.168.1.120 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:38 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc200000-fc20ffff memory:fc210000-fc213fff
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
➜  lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0079:181c DragonRise Inc. TGZ Controller
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2f68:0082 Hoksi Technology DURGOD Taurus K320
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1e71:2007 NZXT NZXT USB Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output for `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`:

Initially it returns nothing, but after running the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
systemctl start bluetooth
sudo modprobe btusb
```

then i get this output

```
➜ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[42389.576251] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[42389.576270] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[42389.576272] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[42389.576274] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[42389.576276] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What does `lsusb` show?

Comment: I don't see BT support in the MB specs. Why do you think it should work
?

Comment: @Pilot6 because it works when i dual boot windows. the motherboard supports bluetooth. https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-B550M-PLUS-WI-FI/techspec/ also i've edited to add lsusb

Comment: Well, then it isn't supported by kernel yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 I find that a bit hard to believe considering when i google, no one else has reported a similar problem with the board. only that ethernet drivers are not available if your kernel is < 5.6. This is using the AX200 intel chip, should be supported?

Comment: Check if it is enabled in BIOS. I don't see any BT devices in `lsusb`.

Comment: And also post output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Should be enabled cause it works in windows, updated question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it - though I'm not sure how. I disconnected and reconnected the modem wires, and then power cycled the computer and it works